# An empty line is added at the end, you need to make n-the number of lines

Tags: python

Python. It is necessary to make n-the number of rows. I succeed, but an empty line is added at the end, how can I remove it?

```
a = int(input())
phrase = "Hello!"
final = f"{phrase} \n"
print (final * a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will look the following:

```
a = int(input())
phrase = "Hello!"*a
final = f"{phrase} \n"
print (final * a,end="")
```

the code addapted to your task is:

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    print("Buy an elephant!")
```

the result would look like this:

```
4
Buy an elephant!
Buy an elephant!
Buy an elephant!
Buy an elephant!
```

Comment: У меня получилось с этим кодом:                                                                                                                   a = int(input())
phrase = "Hello!"
final = f"{phrase} \n"
print (final * a,end="")

Comment: btw you can simply select mine as accepted and then every one will know that my code is the correct answer

Comment: I succeeded with this code, thank you very much, but my supervisor did not accept the code a = int(input())
phrase = "Hello!"
final = f"{phrase} \n"
print (final * a,end="")

Comment: This is my task: Input format
One natural number NN,

Output format
NN lines with the phrase: "Buy an elephant!"